# Why does Jackson ignore @JsonCreator annotation in my auto-generated POJO Enum?

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson, jsonschema2pojo

As usual, there is probaly a very simple solution to my problem:

I have a **JSON schema** snippet that defines the following enum:

```
"title" : {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["Mr", "Miss", "Mrs", "Ms"],
    "description": "The person's title"
 }
```

My company's framework then uses [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#the-maven-plugin) and maven to create the necessary POJO (`Title` lives in `Clazz`, as `title` is part of `clazz` in the JSON schema - with clazz as a name being made up - replace it with employee or customer or whatever you like):

**Generated POJO**

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public static enum Title {

    MR("Mr"),
    MISS("Miss"),
    MRS("Mrs"),
    MS("Ms");
    private final String value;
    private static Map<String, Clazz.Title> constants = new HashMap<String, Clazz.Title>();

    static {
        for (Clazz.Title c: values()) {
            constants.put(c.value, c);
        }
    }

    private Title(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Clazz.Title fromValue(String value) {
        Clazz.Title constant = constants.get(value);
        if (constant == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
        } else {
            return constant;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run a **request** containing the following against it:

```
...
  "title" : "Mr",
...
```

I get this **error** thrown back at me:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of com.example.foo.representations.jaxb.Clazz$Title from String value 'Mr': value not one of declared Enum instance names: [Mr, Miss, Mrs, Ms]  at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@1a372b7; line: 4, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.example.foo.representations.jaxb.MySchema["Clazz"]->com.example.foo.representations.jaxb.Clazz["title"])
```

***Clearly, "Mr" is in the Enum.***

When debugging, I can see that it runs through the following classes (**stack**):

```
findEnum():120, EnumResolver (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util)
deserialize():79, EnumDeserializer (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std)
```

It looks like they are ***only interested in the Enum's "keys"*** (i.e. constants, e.g. "`MR`" instead of "`Mr`"). I'm guessing that the `@JsonCreator` annotation is ignored for some reason.

**Any idea how I can fix that issue?**
Is there a configuration value that might be set anywhere that might cause this behaviour? (I'm working on a big projects; if I know what I need to look for I can search the code base; maybe another developer "misconfigured" something somewhere...) Or might the issue be that `Title` lives in `Clazz`? Do I need to throw an `@JsonProperty` in for good measure? (If so, how exactly?)

We are using jackson-core, -annotations, and -databind 2.4.2.

**Update**: I tried this as a stand-alone project, with the following code, and it worked flawlessly - which means there must be some sort of setting that prevents the annotation from being taken into account...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // create once, reuse
Clazz value = mapper.readValue(new File("resources/data.json"), Clazz.class);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this given your generated class and another simple Pojo type with a `title` field.

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out we had the following in our Spring config:

```
<bean id="mapper" class="com.example.foo.jaxb.links.JsonMapper" />
<!-- ... -->
       <jaxrs:providers>
           <bean id="jsonprovider"
                 class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider">
               <constructor-arg ref="mapper" />
               <constructor-arg>
                   <value></value>
               </constructor-arg>
           </bean>
       </jaxrs:providers>
```

Jsonmapper extends `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, and mostly sets Jackson settings on itself in its constructor. The one thing I had missed in my desperation, however, is this bit of code:

```
// use JAXB annotations (only) 
setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.defaultInstance()));
```

And it pretty much does what it says on the tin, it seems: it stops Jackson from evaluating the `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonValue` annotations. Once the "Jackson annotation suppressor" is gone, all is good.

What I'd like to do is understand how it actually works, so if anyone has any helpful links to docs/how-tos/manuals/books for either the Spring stuff or the suppression of annotations, that would be much appreciated. But in the meantime, this fixes my problem. :)